# Using jQuery as a selector, working with JavaScript, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

```
var helper, kitti, amount;
if (i == 0) { 
    helper = "#k" + ids+ " .contain";
}
else {
    helper = "#k" + ids + " .d" + i;
}    
kitti = "$(" + helper + ").get(0)";
amount = (MouseX-kitti.width / 2) * layer[i - 1] * 2;
kitti.style.transform = "rotateY(" + amount * 50 + "deg)";
kitti.style.left = amount + "px";
```

This part of my code doesn't seem to work but. I bet I did something wrong selecting it? I've read a couple of articles and I came to this conclusion. But it does not work, can you explain me why? How can I select classes with jQuery and after that continue with plain Javascript?

Comment: Try: `kitti=$(helper).get(0)`

Comment: could you try posting better formatted code

Comment: This asker mentions on his SO homepage that he is a hobbyist programmer.  We can't expect him to know all the ins and outs of how to properly format code, so let's be gentle and helpful as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks man that helped! I have made some other mistakes too, but corrected them.

Comment: If an answer provided solves your problem, please click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as the "accepted" solution.

Comment: To give you a better idea of what proper syntax is like, I have edited your code to use commonly accepted JavaScript code formatting.  I think you may agree that it's easier to read this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made some simple syntax errors here.  I personally don't care for the style in which you're written your code, but I will do my best to suggest what the fix might be.

In the second line, you write `kitti = "$(" + helper + ").get(0)"`.  The problem here is that `$` is a function defined in the jQuery library and you are treating it as a string.

The result here will be to assign a string value to the variable `kitti`.  You also appear to be using an undefined variable `ids` in line 1.  The correct syntax would be something like this:

```
var kitti = $(helper).get(0);
```

I don't want to be overbearing, but from the syntax of the code in your question, you might benefit from reading a book on good JavaScript such as "JavaScript: The Good Parts", by Douglas Crockford.  There is also lots of good information available for free on his web site.

Comment: +1 for javascript the good parts. Movie version here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

Comment: I've watched many of Crockford's lectures on the "YUI Theater"; some of the best JavaScript learning experiences ever, IMHO. @dawe69hun would be well advised to be aware that JavaScript has a unique design and history that make it quite different from many other popular languages.